# Ignore "node_modules" from deployment in Google App Engine Java Project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, node-modules

`Google App Engine` java project uses `node modules` for grunt tasks which is used to build the front end. After we run `grunt built`, it gives the `dist` folder to be deployed.

We have following folder structure

```
myproject
   src/
   war/
      app/
      dist/
      node_modules/
      Gruntfile.js
      WEB-INF/
```

We do not want to deploy `node-modules` directory. I have add following in `appengine-web.xml`

```
<static-files>
    <exclude path="/node_modules/*.*" />
</static-files>
```

But it DOES NOT work. How to exclude them from deployment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using resource-files without '.' worked for me.

```
    <resource-files>
        <exclude path="/node_modules/**" />
    </resource-files>
```