# How do you configure the app engine to deploy your app with the node_modules folder in the file stucture?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, node-modules

I'm using grunt with google app engine but every time I try to deploy I have to take the node_modules out of the directory for it to work.

Here is my file structure-

```
    project/
            lib/
            node_modules/
            app/
                static/
                templates/
                __init__.py
                views.py
                models.py
            .gitignore
            README.md
            app.yaml
            appengine_config.py
            Gruntfile.js
            package.json
```

so I have looked at other questions on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083216/ignore-node-modules-from-deployment-in-google-app-engine-java-project) but its for java and I'm using python so how do you configure the app engine to deploy your app with the node_modules folder in the file stucture?   I have ignored all the grunt files and not committed them to my repo so I have no idea any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your `app.yaml` look like?

Comment: I think I figured it out thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the skip_files element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files) in the app's config file:

> The **skip_files** element specifies which files in the application
>   directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine. The value is either a
>   regular expression, or a list of regular expressions. Any filename
>   that matches any of the regular expression is omitted from the list of
>   files to upload when the application is uploaded.

Pay attention at overriding the defaults in that doc section.

Comment: Glad to hear. In such cases submitters should click on the checkmark under the voting arrows to indicate the preferred answer, thus completing the lifecycle of the SO (StackOverflow) Q&As. Thank you notes are not necessary and not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
application: project
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /*.svg
  static_files: app/static/images/images_dest/*.svg
  upload: app/static/images/images_dest/*.svg
  mime_type: image/svg+xml

- url: /static
  static_dir: app/static 

- url: .*
  script: app.app

skip_files:
- ^(node_modules)
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$


libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
```